# Add value to a string

Tags: awk, sed, text

I have a large bash file that has a lot of lines like this:

```
... --env COMP_LABELS="service:service1" ...
```

Where service1 differs in every line. (sometimes it's `service:mgmt` or `service:admin`).

I'm trying to generate some command (probably sed) that would append before the end quote (`"`) the following string: `,branch:$branch`.

So in the first example, it would change into:

```
... --env COMP_LABELS="service:service1,branch:$branch" ...
```

Is it possible to do? Thanks ahead!

(I tried to do something like`sed -i 's/OMP_LABELS=\"service:.*\"/<not sure what to put here since I need to the entire word>/g' filename` but I wasn't sure how to complete it)

Comment: `sed 's/"$/,branch:$branch"/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed, you could simply match a sequence of non-`"` characters following the first `"`:

```
$ echo '... --env COMP_LABELS="service:service1" ...' | 
    sed 's/COMP_LABELS="[^"]*/&,branch:$branch/'
... --env COMP_LABELS="service:service1,branch:$branch" ...
```

Here `/COMP_LABELS="[^"]*/` matches string `COMP_LABELS="` followed by 0 or more non-`"` characters (`^` is a negation operator), then `/&,branch:$branch/` replaces it with whatever was matched on the LHS (`&` is a back-reference) followed by string `,branch:$branch`

Comment: Thanks for the response! That is so cool! May i ask a little about what's going on here? particularly `[^"]*/&`

Comment: @rogersjoshmac I have added a brief explanation